# How to change the image of a JButton?

Tags: java, swing, jbutton

I'm working on a memory game program. I have 30 JButtons on a JPanel. When the user is clicking and finds a match (meaning two buttons with the same image) I want to change the image on the JButton to a different image.  However this does not happen while the program is running.

How can I do this?

I was doing this:

```
cards[i].setIcon(cardBack);
```

where cardBack is an ImageIcon that I already have.

Comment: That is the correct way to change an icon.  Your error is probably somewhere else in the code.

Answer (score 6):

you can use this code:

`Icon i=new ImageIcon("image.jpg");
jButton1.setIcon(i);`

and copy your image (image.jpg) to your project folder!

Answer (score 1):

Use a JToggleButton. More specifically, use the setIcon and setSelectedIcon methods. Using this approach, you'll avoid reinventing the wheel.

Example:

```
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JToggleButton;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.UIManager;

final class JToggleButtonDemo {
    public static final void main(final String[] args) {
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable(){
        @Override
        public void run() {
            createAndShowGUI();
        }
    });
}
private static final void createAndShowGUI(){
    final JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setLayout(new FlowLayout()); // For presentation purposes only.
    final JToggleButton button = new JToggleButton(UIManager.getIcon("OptionPane.informationIcon"));
    button.setSelectedIcon(UIManager.getIcon("OptionPane.errorIcon"));
    frame.add(button);
    frame.pack();
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    frame.setVisible(true);
 }
}
```